# Xamarin navigating pages not working ( MVVM )

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.MainPage"
             xmlns:View="clr-namespace:TravelRecordApp.View">

    <View:MainView/>

</ContentPage>
```

**MainView.xaml**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.View.MainView"
             xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:TravelRecordApp.ViewModel">

    <ContentView.BindingContext>
        <ViewModel:MainViewModel/>
    </ContentView.BindingContext>  
    
        <StackLayout ..>
            <Entry ../>
            <Entry ../>
            <Button Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>
        </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

**app.xaml.cs**

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    //Also Tried MainPage = new MainPage();
}
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public void Login()
{
    bool isEmailEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(EmailEntry);
    bool isPasswordEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordEntry);

    if (isEmailEmpty || isPasswordEmpty)
    {
        
    }
    else
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());
    }
}
```

**HomePage.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TravelRecordApp.View.HomePage">
    <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Hello, this is main page" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**The Problem Is:**

When I debugged the code, I can see it reaches `Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());` after clicking the button, but nothing happens after this point. It's not opening the Home Page.

Comment: how is the VM getting a reference to `Navigation`?  And is it executing on the UI thread?

Comment: I just used ContentPage as a base class also for the VM but it seems really wrong since it is not actually a page.. So how to navigate from VM then?

Comment: you can use `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation`

Answer (score 0):

1. As Jason said, you can try to use `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());`
2. Using "Xamarin.Forms Shell" navigation is a great way to navigate between pages. For details, please refer to:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation.